# How to animate images and container simultaneously?

Tags: android, animation

I have a layout with 2 images, on click on any one of the image, the clicked image should scale up and the other should scale down, simultaneously and the container in which they are, should also move up in height, as there are some text to be shown below the images.

How to achieve this functionality, what type of animations should i use, as all three should happen simultaneously.

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use scale animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

#### See [this link for scale up and scale down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926117/objectanimator-with-scale-property-makes-bg-black)

> sample code

```
ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 0.5f);
ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 0.5f);
scaleDownX.setDuration(1000);
scaleDownY.setDuration(1000);

AnimatorSet scaleDown = new AnimatorSet();
scaleDown.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY);

scaleDownX.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
         View p= (View) v.getParent();
         p.invalidate();
     });
scaleDown.start();
```

Comment: Thank you @NJ , so what would be a good place to start learning animation, as i am new to android and animation.

Comment: Glad to help you,  do vote up and accept if it helped you

Comment: yeah, i upvoted your answer, i am trying to implement it, in my current project. Can you please recommend a good place or some links, to start with basic animations in android.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0ahUKEwiCuviDn-_KAhVRBI4KHcVgA6kQtwIIVDAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D3UbJhmkeSig&usg=AFQjCNGQ2KVPwHxRGItwKb5ufXFAlVUDeA&sig2=J3GCrTpMwWHDgN7SXYFZkQ&bvm=bv.113943164,d.c2E&cad=rja

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html