# Run animation on different views together

Tags: android, animation

I need to animate 2 views and I want the animation to start together. Here are my two animations:

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation1 = new ScaleAnimation(image.getScaleX(), 1.0f, image.getScaleY(), 1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
scaleAnimation.setDuration(300);
scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
scaleAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
image.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);

ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation2 = new ScaleAnimation(logo.getScaleX(), 1.0f, logo.getScaleY(), 1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
scaleAnimation.setDuration(300);
scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
scaleAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
logo.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

How can I do it? I need to do it programatically.

**P.S.** I don't have much experience in animation.

Comment: Check out this example : http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1194

Comment: @ItzikSamara that is for running two animations simultaneously on a single view. I want to start 2 different animations on 2 different views at the same time.

Comment: OK check out this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926117/objectanimator-with-scale-property-makes-bg-black its ObjectAnimator .. a bit different but i am using it works great.

Comment: Check this basic introduction. Ideally you can either start two different animation on a button click or starting of an activity say in onResume.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample for you )

```
public class AnimationUtils {
    public static void applyAnimation(Context context, View view, int animationResource, int animationOffsetMilisec){
        Animation anim = android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, animationResource);
        anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        anim.setStartOffset(animationOffsetMilisec);
        if(view != null) {
            view.setAnimation(anim);
            view.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }
}
```

`animation_tap.xml` must be in res/anim/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.00"
        android:toYScale="0.95"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>
    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.95"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="100"/>
</set>
```

and now whatever in code you can use:

```
AnimationUtils.applyAnimation(context,view1,R.anim.animation_tap,0);
AnimationUtils.applyAnimation(context,view2,R.anim.animation_tap,0);
AnimationUtils.applyAnimation(context,view3,R.anim.animation_tap,0);
//...
```